# How to run the server of vscode LSP server from terminal? how to convert it to binary?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, language-server-protocol

I am using lsp-sample and when I run the server from vscode, I am able to run it on portal 6009. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples

This is the other relevant link related to LSP in vscode https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide

I want to run this server from terminal which I am not able to do. How to do this?
I basically want to use this same LSP server from intellij. How can I make this server to a binary?